# Filter URL Parameters

Tags: lightning-experience, dashboard

In the Salesforce Spring '21 Release Notes, I read about the new feature of saving dashboard results including filters
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_rd_dashboards_filter_url.htm&type=5&release=230

The example given in the Notes shows 2 filters with the 'equal to' criteria.
Can anyone help me to get the URI code for filters with criteria like
'contains'
'starts with'
'between'
'not equal to'
'less than'
etc.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can create or edit existing Dashboard and click on '+Filter' you can view options (contains,less than, greater than etc.,).

Check below screenshot

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi Vinay, thanks for the input, but I was looking for something else.  When you have a dashboard with filters, you can add them in the url, so that when you open the url, the filter is already set.  I wanted to know the uri code for 'contains' or 'starts with', so that I could create those url's and provide to certain users.  Thanks!